# Adding custom annotation to Spring roo method in controller

Tags: spring-roo

Spring Roo automatically generates CRUD methods for the controller.  Can I add a custom annotation to one of the generated methods?  Normally you would put it on top of the method but there are none to annotate.

```
@RequestMapping("/pizzas")
@Controller
@RooWebScaffold(path = "pizzas", formBackingObject = Pizza.class)
@RooWebJson(jsonObject = Pizza.class)
public class PizzaController {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to push-in the method and then you can modify it as needed.

Comment: what do you mean by push-in?  Do you mean define the method inside the controller?  That sort of defeats the point of roo because then I have to manually implement the code for all CRUD operations just to add a simple one line annotation.  I want to add an annotation that alters the json response.

Comment: It doesn't defeat nothing, Roo generates the code and offers a way to customize it without modifying your changes ... what you want to do is a code customization. On the other side, Roo lets you to develop and use custom add-ons for those code generation that are usual for you.