# How to change code generation/templates in spring roo

Tags: spring-roo

I want to know if and how I can change the templates that generate the code in a ROO-Project.

There is a corresponding .aj-file for each controller, that is generated by ROO.
I know it is possible to override the methods in the .java-file, but I don't want to do that. I would like to change the template so that all generated .aj-files contain my changes.

I've worked quite a bit with Grails. There you can use the command "install-templates". Afterwards you can completly customize the scaffolding logic to your needs. Thats exactly what I am looking for in ROO as well.

I was not able to find a solution for that. Here are some jira tickets, but I didn't understand if and how I could achieve my goal:

- [Templates to generate controllers and views (scaffolding) should be customizable](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-168)
- [Review templating approach to be more flexible and allow better custom branding of generated applications](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-8)
- [Adding custom annotation to Spring roo method in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034893/adding-custom-annotation-to-spring-roo-method-in-controller)

Any idea if that is even possible?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, *Currently*, you have this options:

- create *your own add-on* which creates the *scaffolding* as you want in the same way there are add-ons for JSF or GTK (see [Simple add-on documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/simple-addons.html) and referred add-ons source code ).
- Create an add-on that generates you own *.aj* files for you controllers to include you custom behaviour (see [Simple add-on documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/simple-addons.html))

This is no a easy thing. I my opinion, only If you need do this customization in some projects (more than 3 or 4 project by example) and the logic will evolve you worth create an add-on.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, first: What do you mean by "currently"? I looked a bit through the jira but could not find a corresponding ticket. second: I looked into the addon-web-mvc-controller and changed it. It worked though using my own roo-installation. But the better way to go would be to enable the addon-web-mvc-controller to use a custom template like in grails: install-templates!? Any ideas how that could work?

Comment: 1. I mean "currently" nobody do it, but you can do it ;). 2. The first thing is create a "proof of concept" with what you like to how Roo generate the project (without the "web mvc setup"). Then create your own add-on which automates the actions which you do on your _proof_ (I think that modify the addon-web-mvc-controller is not a good idea, but you can _copy/use_ some _classes/methods_ on your add-on).